# Java: ExceptionInInitializerError Creating New Instance of Clojure Compiled Class Loaded with Custom Class Loader

Tags: java, reflection, clojure, classloader

I am dynamically loading a jar and attempting to create a new instance of a given class in the jar.  To make matters more interesting, the jar was compiled from a Leiningen clojure project.  I created a custom byte class loader:

```
private static class ByteClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private final Map<String, byte[]> classDataMap;

    public ByteClassLoader() {
        this.classDataMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addClassData(String className, byte[] bytes) {
        classDataMap.put(className, bytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(final String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        byte[] classData = classDataMap.get(name);
        if (classData != null)
            return defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
        return super.findClass(name);
    }
}
```

Now I get the class I am interested in from the custom class loader and attempt to create a new instance.

```
    Class<?> myClass = byteClassLoader.findClass("com.example.Foo");
    myClass.newInstance();
```

But this throws a file not found exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate some/namespace.class or some/namespace.clj on classpath: 
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:407)
at com.example.Foo.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 33 more
```

It seems like the call to new instance doesn't know about the custom class loader.  Does that sound like a correct understanding of the error?  How do I instantiate a Foo in this example?

Comment: In a somewhat similar situation, calling something akin to `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(byteClassLoader);` solved my problem. Try calling this prior to `myClass.newInstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

The created class *does* “know” about its defining `ClassLoader` and the JVM will resolve its references using the defining class loader. However, as you can see from your stack trace, its the `clojure.lang.RT.load` which tries to resolve resources in an incompatible way. By looking at its code, it boils down to the [following method](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L2083):

```
static public ClassLoader baseLoader(){
    if(Compiler.LOADER.isBound())
        return (ClassLoader) Compiler.LOADER.deref();
    else if(booleanCast(USE_CONTEXT_CLASSLOADER.deref()))
        return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    return Compiler.class.getClassLoader();
}
```

From this code you can derive solutions to your problem:

1. You may set the value of `Compiler.LOADER` to your custom class loader.
2. If `Compiler.LOADER` remains unbound and `RT.USE_CONTEXT_CLASSLOADER` evaluates to `true`, you can set the [context loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setContextClassLoader(java.lang.ClassLoader)) of your thread to your custom class loader.
3. last but not least, if you enforce your class loader to be the defining class loader of the entire clojure code, `Compiler.class.getClassLoader()` will return your custom class loader.